# Working with ProjectLocker

Tags: eclipse, svn, git, projectlocker

I have an account in [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com/) and a project in [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/).
How to upload this in ProjectLocker?

Answer (score 2):

I'll make the assumption that you want to use Subversion, as I don't know what support MyEclipse has for Git.

ProjectLocker's Subversion is 100% standard, so adding a project is the same as it would be for any other Subversion repository.  The URL for projects of which you are a member is presented on the home page.  You should be able to right-click on your project, select Team. . . Share Project, and then add the ProjectLocker repository with the URL, name, and password you were issued.  This connects your local project with the ProjectLocker repository, and then you can add and update files as you see fit.

If you already have files uploaded, you can use the SVN Repository Exploring perspective to find the project and directory and check out a new project.

Answer (score 0):

ProjectLocker offers subversion and git repositories. First you obviously have to decide for one or another version control system and add the required plugins to eclipse (for subversion or for git unless MyEclipse already has the connectors).

Then it's pretty straightforward - add your repository (ProjectLocker should provide you the correct URL) and *share* the project.